# reloadData is not calling cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I know this topic has been raised quite a few times but I can't seem to get through.

This is a simple `UITableViewController` who's cells are either normal `UITableViewCells` or custom ones.

This allow users to input text in a `textField` in a cell and add it directly to the `tableView`.

When the user is done entering his text he hits return and the new entry gets added to `listOfItems`. At this point I want my `tableView` to reload its data to show the last item added.

Doesn't seem to work.

```
class CreateListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: - Model

    var listOfItems = [String]()
        {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
            println(listOfItems)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - View LifeCycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listOfItems.count + 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row + 1 == listOfItems.count{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCellSearch", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListItemTableViewCell
            cell.configure(text: "", placeholder: "Enter an item")
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
            println(indexPath.row)
            cell.textLabel?.text = listOfItems[indexPath.row]
            return cell

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
class ListItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var cellTextField: UITextField!

var controllerArray = CreateListTableViewController()

func configure(#text: String?, placeholder: String){
    cellTextField.text = text
    cellTextField.placeholder = placeholder

    cellTextField.accessibilityValue = text
    cellTextField.accessibilityLabel = placeholder
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.text = ""
    return true
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    cellTextField.delegate = self
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    controllerArray.listOfItems += [textField.text]
    textField.text = ""
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return true
}


override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Interestingly reloadData calls 'numberOfRows' but not 'cellForRow'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexes/sizes are off such that your code only works when listOfItems' size is 0. Try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listOfItems.count + 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == listOfItems.count {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCellSearch", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListItemTableViewCell
        cell.configure(text: "", placeholder: "Enter an item")
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        println(indexPath.row)
        cell.textLabel?.text = listOfItems[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }
}
```

Update:

OK, the problem is that in ListItemTableViewCell you are creating a new instance of CreateListTableViewController and assigning it to controllerArray. This means that when you call controllerArray.listOfItems += [textField.text], you are calling it on a separate, second instance of CreateListTableViewController that is not on the screen.

Instead, you should leave controllerArray uninitialized in ListItemTableViewCell and then set it from cellForRowAtIndexPath like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row + 1 == listOfItems.count{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCellSearch", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListItemTableViewCell
        cell.configure(text: "", placeholder: "Enter an item")
        cell.controllerArray = self
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        println(indexPath.row)
        cell.textLabel?.text = listOfItems[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the problem persists. I've checked what happened after reloadData was called and it simply doesn't invoke cellForRowAtIndexPath. Is that normal?

Comment: It's not normal. cellForRowAtIndexPath should be called after reloadData until cells for all rows/sections have been created or the tableView is "filled" with cells. You may need to post more of your code to get a solution. I would set a breakpoint on tableView.reloadData() to be sure that is getting called and another breakpoint in numberOfRowsInSection which should be called after reloadData(). From that breakpoint, ensure that the size of listOfItems is what you expect.

Comment: You're not setting/adding to listOfItems anywhere in the code you posted. I'm guess you are doing that somewhere but just didn't post the code. Is that right?

Comment: Let me add that a better design would be to make CreateListTableViewController the textField delegate and then moving your textFieldShould... methods to CreateListTableViewController. in cellForRowAtIndexPath, make your table view controller the delegate with cell.cellTextField.delegate = self, then get rid of the controllerArray variable in ListItemTableViewCell. This moves your "controlling" code out of the "view" and into the "controller".

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that your internal list is updated correctly and the numberOfRowsInSection functions returns number other than 0 or 1?

Comment: Checked that, and all seems ok